# weird C# compiler error: cyclic inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, compiler-errors

I came across the following error a few days ago, in one of our C# applications here at work. Here's how the error message looks like:

> "Inherited interface '...ResourceManager.ResourcesManager' causes a cycle in the interface hierarchy of '...ResourceManager.IResourcesManagerView' in D:...\Common\ResourceManager\IResourcesManagerView.cs"

This always happens on my machine, but on the build machine there's a 50-50 chance the build will succeed. My class 'ResourceManager' implements an interface 'IResourcesManagerView', which also implements several interfaces, one of which is a generic interface named IInitializable. I have found the following workaround: declare a dummy interface IDummy implementing IInitializable.

But that doesn't make any sense to me. Has anyone come across this issue?
I use Windows XP, Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: You should shorten IInitializable to were it still produces the bug and post the code required to recreate.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the compiler. Joel, if this is still an issue in your code base, could you please try creating a small self-contained project that has just enough code to reproduce this issue and file a bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/?

You can also try Visual Studio 2010 as if this is a bug it may already be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add a Class Diagram to visualize the problem. Something tells me you aren't using one now.

2) Minimize the problem to something you can post. But you will probably find it yourself along the way.

Best Guess: Smells like there are 2 versions of IInitializable or maybe IResourcesManagerView around.

Comment: My object implements two methods named the same IInitializable, but one is generic. Also, they both have a method "void Deinit()", which is implemented in the class by one public method (implicit implementation). I will have a look at the class diagram also.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably referencing the same, but different version assembly containing the interface.  Make sure you reference common assemblies from the same location.

Comment: It's unlikely that this happens. Also, it doesn't explain why adding the IDummy solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same compilation error, fixed it (sort of) and formalized it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188355/inherited-interface-causes-a-cycle-in-the-interface-hierarchy).
But it might be a different problem than yours.