# Inherited interface causes a cycle in the interface hierarchy

Tags: c#

I get the following error

> Inherited interface 'ConsoleApplicationTest.Program.B' causes a cycle
>   in the interface hierarchy of 'ConsoleApplicationTest.Program.IB'

when I try to compile this code :

```
public interface IA<T>
{
}

public abstract class A<T> : IA<T>
{
}

public interface IB : IA<B.C>
{
}

public class B : A<B.C>, IB
{
    public class C
    {
    }
}
```

This is easily fixed by :

- extracting `class C` of `class B`.

OR

- modifying `interface IB<T> : IA<T>` and `class B : A<B.C>, IB<B.C>` (but that leads to modify every use of `interface IB` in the code)

But this does not explain why I get this compilation error. Any idea ?